# Why in django form.as_p shows errors, and form.non_field_errors does not

Tags: django, error-handling, django-templates

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Works fine and returns error message, when I try to fill field with wring data.
And

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
{% for f in form %}
    {{ f }}
    {{ f.errors }}
{% endfor %}
```

Does not, even with:

```
{% if f.errors %}
    {% for error in f.errors %}
        {{ error.as_text }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If you just do `{{ form.errors }}` without looping, does it show the errors?

Comment: Nope, that was first thing I tried

Comment: In your views.py, can you print `form.errors` if `form.is_valid()` is `False`? Are you able to share the error message?

Comment: Interesting thing, I don't use `is_valid()`

Comment: Then you have no way to tell if your form is valid or not. You can only have errors when a `form.is_valid()` is `False`. Read this section of django doc for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: But why `form.as_p` works then?

Comment: I couldn't determine by the information you gave, maybe you are using different data that makes the form validation passes somehow. But bottom line is that you can at least print `form.errors` in your views.py to check if the form actually has errors, then try to fix your frontend if it does.

Comment: Ok, I'll check. I use `RegexValodator` with `message` field in constructor. Which I'm waiting to receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.as_p` handles the form error automatically but if you want to list fields separately, you also need to handle errors manually for every field. Try this...

```
{{form.field_name.errors}}
```

for every `field_name` separately.